# Print AngularJS application

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

We have a complex AngularJS-based application with different loaded stylesheets. I need to print the separate page with nice styling, exactly how it looks in the browser, plus several elements need to be opened via ng-show for the print.
Looking for potential existing solutions, I've found the following AngularJS directive: https://dzone.com/articles/building-simple-angularjs. I had to slightly update it to load css stylesheets. Eventually, when I click the Print button, I can generate the huge HTML file with css references in `<head/>`. Being posted directly into browser, it looks more or less nice, but:

1. Ng-show /ng-hide are fully ignored, and that is expectable. How to deal with it?
2. Mostly important - when I try to Ctrl-P this HTML, it doesn't looks nice in preview at all. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand, do you generate a *new* file for printing? You should just use the exact same page, but a custom made stylesheet that's applied when the user presses print in his browser.

Comment: To answer _What I'm doing wrong?_ You have to show _What have u done so far?_

Comment: Eventually, thanks to Matsemann, I was able to print AngularJS page in Chrome almost exactly how it looks in the browser, with colors, layout etc. So far so good. But FF and IE look weird. They don't keep the same layout, all colors are lost, no backgrounds. Should it be completely different approach of how to print on those two browsers?